# scifi dystopian movie possibly horror elements as well from the 70s-80s the twist is that main villian and the protagonist are brothers

Tags: story-identification, movie, dystopia

I have been looking for this movie for 20 years. I remember it being on TCM once but I did not watch it. It is possibly a dystopian movie in which has some sci-fi and possibly horror aspects in which the main villain and hero turn out to be brothers.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you recall _any_ of the horror/sci-fi elements?  Is it set in the present day, future or past?  Any advanced (for the time) technology?  How is the setting dystopian?  Mind control, secret police, universal drug use...?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: I'm afraid there's really not enough details here to come up with anything that's a reasonable "correct" answer, as evidenced that we have 4 movies already that hit the criteria.

Comment: Indeed, protagonist and antagonist turning out to be brothers is one of the variations on [a fairly common trope](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SeparatedAtBirth).  It's not so very distinguishing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could this be the 1981 David Cronenberg movie Scanners?

•   “from the 70s-80s" - Released in 1981

•   “on TCM” over 20 years ago - I can’t speak for TCM specifically, but it still gets aired in the UK to this day.

•   “possibly a dystopian movie” – Large Corporations treating some of the general population as guinea pigs for medical experiments.  Scanner factions intent on starting a war.

•   “some Sci-Fi” – Hacking computers with psychic powers.  Pharmaceuticals that imbue and subdue the Scanner ability.

•   “possibly horror” – Exploding heads

•   “the main villain and hero turn out to be brothers” – They do indeed

Comment: I think this is the one. My dad told me about this film years ago and when he passed I didn’t know what it was and I wanted to watch it. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

Might you be thinking of *[Wizards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizards_(film))* by Ralph Bakshi?

> Earth has been devastated by a nuclear war. It takes 2 million years for the radioactive clouds to allow sunlight in. The humans who survived the apocalypse have been transformed into mutants, while humanity's true ancestors  – fairies, elves and dwarves – resurface and live in the idyllic land of Montagar.
>
> While her people celebrate 3,000 years of peace, Delia, queen of the fairies, falls into a trance and gives birth to twin wizards: the kindhearted Avatar and his evil, mutated brother Blackwolf. After Delia's death years later, Blackwolf attempts to usurp her leadership, but Avatar defeats him in a magical duel. Blackwolf leaves Montagar, vowing to return and "make this a planet where mutants rule".

### Trailer

Answer (score 10):

Could this be [Gattaca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gattaca)?

- It's a dystopian sci-fi
- The investigator trying to find the protagonist turns out to be his brother
- It came out 25 years ago, so you could plausibly have seen it 20 years ago
- According to Google, it has a page on the TCM website, though I can't confirm that as TCM is unavailable in my region: [image: Google results for "TCM Gattaca"]

Answer (score 4):

You could be thinking of the 1995 [Judge Dredd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judge_Dredd_(film)) film.  It's a bit later than your guess of 70s/80s, but it certainly would have been on cable by the late 90s or early 2000s, and the Judge Dredd comics date back to the 70s.

> some sci-fi and possibly horror aspects

Judge Dredd is set in a dystopian future.  The film features a great deal of casual killing, shown fairly graphically, as well as mutant characters.

> the main villain and hero turn out to be brothers

To quote the Wikipedia article: "*Dredd, one of the most dedicated Street Judges, has been framed for murder by his own half-brother — the psychotic Rico, who plots to take over Mega-City One with an army of superhuman clones.*"